# Using UIMA, Stanford Core NLP together

Tags: nlp, tokenize, stanford-nlp, opennlp, uima

The UIMA and the StanfordNLP produces the output after the pipeline of operation like if We want to do POS tagging so in the input text first the tokenization is done and then the POS tagging.

I want to use the tokenization of the UIMA and use that token in the POS tagger of the Stanford CoreNLP. But the POS tagger of Stanford CoreNLP have the requirement to run the tokenizer before POS tagger.

So, is it possible to use the different API in the same pipeline or not ?
Is it possible to use the UIMA tokenizer and the Stanford CoreNLP together ?

Comment: How different is UIMA tokenizer from Stanford tokenizer?

Comment: Also, I don't get why you want to use UIMA tokenizer

Comment: @Daniel The different between the UIMA and the Standford Tokenizer is that they will be provide the output in the different data structure. We can extract the tokens from those data structure but how to use the tokens created by UIMA tokenizer in the POS taggging of the Standford POS Tagger. Like I try to run the Standford POS with the properties 

Properties props = new Properties();
 props.put("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos");

If I try to run as:
Properties props = new Properties();
 props.put("annotators", "pos");

It gives error due to tokenizer and ssplit is missing.

Comment: @Daniel The objective is not only to use the UIMA Tokenizer but to use the UIMA and the Standford NLP or the open NLP in the same pipeline. e.g. Using the Tokenizer and the Word to Sentence splitter from the Standford NLP and then using the POS tagger of the OpenNLP.

Comment: What I mean is that, how different is these two Tokenizers? Can you think of an example in which Stanford tokenization is not acting as good as it should (maybe like UIMA)?

Comment: @ Daniel The question is not only about the particular Tokenizer and it's use but it's about these API together in the same pipeline, Tokenizer is just a example that I have used to explain my problem.

Comment: I see. But I don't one can give a general solution for any step in this pipeline. Each step in this pipeline might be replaceable, but it might be different from replacing other steps.

Answer (score 5):

The typical approach to combine analysis steps from different tool chains (e.g. [OpenNLP](http://opennlp.apache.org), [Stanford  CoreNLP](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/corenlp.shtml), etc.) in UIMA would be to wrap each of them as a UIMA analysis engine. The analysis engine serves as an adapter between the UIMA data structure (the CAS) and the data structures used be the individual tools (e.g. the OpenNLP POS tagger or the CoreNLP parser). At the level of UIMA, these components can then be combined into pipelines.

There are various collections of UIMA components that wrap such tool chains, e.g. [ClearTK](https://cleartk.github.io/cleartk/), [DKPro Core](https://dkpro.github.io/dkpro-core/), or [U-Compare](http://nactem.ac.uk/ucompare/).

The following example combines the OpenNLP segmenter (tokenizer/sentence splitter) and Stanford CoreNLP parser (which also creates the POS tags in the present example). The example is implemented as a [Groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org) script employing the [uimaFIT API](http://uima.apache.org/uimafit.html) to create and run a pipeline using from components of the DKPro Core collection.

```groovy
#!/usr/bin/env groovy
@Grab(group='de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core', 
      module='de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.opennlp-asl', 
      version='1.5.0')
@Grab(group='de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core', 
      module='de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.stanfordnlp-gpl', 
      version='1.5.0')

import static org.apache.uima.fit.pipeline.SimplePipeline.*;
import static org.apache.uima.fit.util.JCasUtil.*;
import static org.apache.uima.fit.factory.AnalysisEngineFactory.*;
import org.apache.uima.fit.factory.JCasFactory;

import de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.opennlp.*;
import de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.stanfordnlp.*;
import de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.api.segmentation.type.*;
import de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.api.syntax.type.*;

def jcas = JCasFactory.createJCas();
jcas.documentText = "This is a test";
jcas.documentLanguage = "en";

runPipeline(jcas,
  createEngineDescription(OpenNlpSegmenter),
  createEngineDescription(StanfordParser,
    StanfordParser.PARAM_WRITE_PENN_TREE, true));

select(jcas, Token).each { println "${it.coveredText} ${it.pos.posValue}" }

select(jcas, PennTree).each { println it.pennTree }
```

Its output (after a lot of logging output) should look like this:

```
This DT
is VBZ
a DT
test NN
(ROOT
  (S
    (NP (DT This))
    (VP (VBZ is)
      (NP (DT a) (NN test)))))
```

I gave the Groovy script as an example because it works out of the box. A Java program would look quite similar, but would typically use e.g. Maven or Ivy to obtain the required libraries.

In case you want to try the script and need more information on installing Groovy and on potential trouble-shooting, you can find more information [here](https://dkpro.github.io/dkpro-core/groovy/recipes/).

*Disclosure: I am working on the DKPro Core and Apache UIMA uimaFIT projects.*

Answer (score 4):

There are at least two ways to handle this if you want to use CoreNLP as the pipeline.

1. Force CoreNLP to ignore the requirements.

   ```java
   Properties props = new Properties();
   props.put("enforceRequirements", "false");
   props.put("annotators", "pos");
   ```

   This will get rid of the "missing requirements" error.  However, the POSTaggerAnnotator in CoreNLP expects         the tokens to be CoreLabel objects and expects the sentences to be CoreMap objects (instantiated as ArrayCoreMap) so you'll have to convert them.
2. Add custom annotators to the pipeline.

   The CoreMaps/CoreLabels are maps with classes as keys so you'll need a class/key for your custom annotation:

   ```java
   public class CustomAnnotations {        

       //this class will act as a key
       public static class UIMATokensAnnotation 
               implements CoreAnnotation<List<CoreLabel>> {        

           //getType() defines/restricts the Type of the value associated with this key
           public Class<List<CoreLabel>> getType() {
               return ErasureUtils.<Class<List<CoreLabel>>> uncheckedCast(List.class);
           }
       }  
   }
   ```

   You will also need an annotator class:

   ```java
   public class UIMATokensAnnotator implements Annotator{

       //this constructor signature is expected by StanfordCoreNLP.class
       public UIMATokensAnnotator(String name, Properties props) {
           //initialize whatever you need
       }

       @Override
       public void annotate(Annotation annotation) {
           List<CoreLabel> tokens = //run the UIMA tokenization and convert output to CoreLabels   
           annotation.set(CustomAnnotations.UIMATokensAnnotation.class, tokens);
       }

       @Override
       public Set<Requirement> requirementsSatisfied() {
           return Collections.singleton(TOKENIZE_REQUIREMENT);
       }

       @Override
       public Set<Requirement> requires() {
           return Collections.emptySet();
       }

   }
   ```

   finally:

   ```java
   props.put("customAnnotatorClass.UIMAtokenize", "UIMATokensAnnotator")
   props.put("annotators", "UIMAtokenize, ssplit, pos")
   ```

   The UIMA/OpenNLP/etc. sentence annotation can be added as a custom annotator in a similar fashion.
   Check out http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/corenlp-faq.shtml#custom for a condensed version of option #2.